# Building a deck - can I extend the side wall vent of my propane furnace underneath it?

Tags: walls, furnace, ventilation, propane

I'm building a low deck outside of my house, and the vent wouldn't have a 1ft clearance. Deck extends about 7ft out from the house. Would it cause any problems if I were to extend the vent's 2inch piping out that 7ft to the end of the deck, and through holes in the deck's siding?

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need further details!

Comment: What's the make and model of the furnace?  How long is the existing vent, and how many 90º angles are in it?

Comment: Furnace is Frigidaire, not sure of model. About 9ft vent currently, 2 90 degree angles

Comment: The documentation for the unit should specify the maximum vent length. You'll either need the documentation, or the exact model number so you can find the documentation online.